# Kibana dashboard doesn't display logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm a total newbie to elastisearch who is trying to finish this tutorial:

http://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/11/19/collect-visualize-your-logs-logstash-elasticsearch-redis-kibana/

I followed the steps but Kibana dashborad remains empty, i.e., no data is being sent to it. The logs I only want to send is data from the syslog. I tried to investigate what's wrong and found that when entering this in a browser:

```
http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty
```

Returns only:

```
{ }
```

Following further I learnt that this is something do with indexes or indices (sill can't figure out the difference) and most likely a config file I have is not correct.

My questions is what file needs to be re-written? Anything specific I'm missing? Any resources that would help me to understand more?

Comment: Indexes and indices is both plural for index, so it's the same. Seems like you have no index and therefore no data is stored in your elasticsearch

Comment: The request you are doing does not return indices, it returns aliases. Did you check elasticsearch for data? Did you monitor redis? Did you output logstash using stdout? A lot of things to try.